# How can i add custom rounded swipe actions in swiftui?

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

in my SwiftUI App, i want to design rounded swipe actions in ListView, as you can see in the following example (Weather App iOS 15)

[image]

I know that you can add custom actions like this:

```swift
List {
    Text("Pepperoni pizza")
        .swipeActions {
            Button("Order") {
                print("Awesome!")
            }
            .tint(.green)
        }

    Text("Pepperoni with pineapple")
        .swipeActions {
            Button("Burn") {
                print("Right on!")
            }
            .tint(.red)
        }
}
```

but how can i make this swipe actions rounded? I know that i can change the listRowBackground, but in this case the results looks like this. That is not what i want

[image]

Do i need to develop a custom VStack and HStack or should i use UITableView with UIViewRepresentable? What is better in this case? Any suggestions?

Comment: custom one be the only way right now.

Comment: @swiftPunk could you give me a quick example?

Comment: I think I can make a simple project for start, I will gave an answer.

Comment: @swiftPunk thank you, i will wait for your answer 

Comment: Are you want it just for learning or for using in a real app?

Comment: @swiftPunk i want to use it in a real app

Comment: I made something like this like 8 month ago but I must refactor it and clean it up a little, is it what you looking? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmiuc.gif

Comment: @swiftPunk Yes, it's going in the right direction. I would just like there to be a gap between the swipe actions and the content (as you can see on the first image)

Comment: @swiftPunk thanks for the offer, if so I need someone to help me create a 7 day calendar view for iPad (use CalendarKit)

Comment: Can we talk or text in private?

Comment: @swiftPunk please sent me a message at: https://telegram.me/niklasgrewe

Comment: Can we have the solution to this?

Comment: @DanielZanchi unfortunately, there is no solution, as there was no cooperation. Also, I'm developing my app more in UIKit again as I'm still missing too many things in SwiftUI. Sorry, but at this point I can't help you. This video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmxOxQOsNpA

Comment: Is there another solution? With this tutorial that's possible but not in a scrollview or list, because the gesture cpaptures all drag gestures