# Round corner when swipe in a List - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using Swift3 & iOS 15, I have the following:

[image]

```
Button(role: .destructive) {
    
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
}
```

How do I make that right side on swipe rounded? I tried placing under the label `.cornerRadius(15)` but it won't do the trick, and I don't want to round the whole list, just that right part when the user swipes.

Comment: It isn't possible right now, This has been asked several times lately

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, I'll leave it open so when it's done it can be updated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008986/how-can-i-add-custom-rounded-swipe-actions-in-swiftui

Comment: @swiftPunk yes, the right corner to be like that, but in a native way if possible, not 100 lines of code to implement a corner radius lol

Comment: @Arturo: I am afraid that would not possible, it need custom code.

Comment: How many lines would custom be? @swiftPunk

Comment: @Arturo: It depends on your design and your skill in SwiftUI, some pro developer could make it less code, some could make more code for idiot prof safety! it depend on the developer.

Comment: That's true @swiftPunk if you want post your answer here, If it works I'll accept it and once we get a native approach someone can add it later on :)

Comment: @Arturo Is this when using `swipeActions` on a `List`?

Comment: @George yes, `.swipeActions() { Button... }`

Comment: You can use .clipShape() to round only right corners. clipShape() takes a Shape as an argument and uses it as a clipping mask for the view it is applied to. And that shape in your case will be a Path of a rectangle with only right corners rounded. You can clip any View like that, including Button, of course.

As for the list, I guess, you'll have to create custom list view for you application...

Comment: @Chus that doesn't seem to work. If I put it on the label I posted above it doesn't recognize it and if I put it some levels above the Button I would be modifying the row of the List and I don't want that. I only want to modify the button

Comment: @Arturo Put it on Button itself, not on Label, nor on any higher level. Create a Button like this: Button(action: yourAction, label: { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill") } ).clipShape(yourClippingPath).

Comment: @Chus nop, that doesn't work either, this is what I wrote: `Button(action: {
                // someAction here
            }) {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0, style: .continuous))
            }`

Comment: @Arturo You're still clipping Label, not Button. Try this: Button(action: {}, label: { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill") } ).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0, style: .continuous))

Comment: @Chus I literally copy pasted your code and doesn't work :/

Comment: So how do I do it using custom then? @swiftPunk I don't see code in ticktock lol

Comment: @Arturo: I just wanted show that any design is possible with custom code! The limitations are your mind! But with API you can do what apple offers! The codes are long I could not upload or show there.